# How fast can Ubuntu 13.10 drive an Intel dual-band 7260?

Tags: iwlwifi

I have a System76 laptop with an i7 and Intel Dual-Band 7260 card.  It runs Ubuntu 13.10.  My router is a Netgear R7000.  I have a gigabit connection.  Going through the router over Ethernet, various speedtest sites (http://speedtest.net, http://speeds.mygrande.net/, http://speedtest.comcast.net/) rate my connection at 700-900Mbps.  Going over wireless, talking over the 5Ghz channel, sitting five feet away from the router, I can get about 300Mbps.

Should the 13.10 Intel driver with the iwlwifi-7260-ucode-22.1 firmware be able to go faster than 300Mbps?

Answer (score 1):

I think [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2178873) answers my question.  Quote:

> It was bugging me that I couldn't remember where I had read the 7260ac
>   would only get ac speeds on 3.13+ kernels... so dug around (again).
>   Here's the link to the discussion I came across:
>
> http://www.linux.org/threads/wireless-speed-capped.4324/
>
> Post #14 had the reply from Intel that stated ac speeds would only be
>   available on 3.13+ kernels (you'll need to expand the post to see
>   Intel's reply).

As I understand it, Ubuntu 14.04 will ship with the 3.13 kernel.

**Edit:** I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 on the same machine.  The wireless speed is still significantly below where it ought to be.  Whatever the problem is, Ubuntu 14.04 does not fix it.